# How to obtain count of parent foreign key from child table using Room

Tags: android, join, sqlite, foreign-keys, android-room

I have a parent entity Collection:

```
@Entity(tableName = "collections")
public class Collection implements Serializable {

    @PrimaryKey
    @NonNull
    public String id;

    public String collTitle;

    public int isFavorite;

    public int wordCount;

    Collection(String collTitle, int isFavorite, int wordCount) {
        this(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), collTitle, isFavorite, wordCount);
    }

    @Ignore
    Collection(@NonNull String id, String collTitle, int isFavorite, int wordCount) {
        this.id = id;
        this.collTitle = collTitle;
        this.isFavorite = isFavorite;
        this.wordCount = wordCount;
    }

}
```

and a child entity Word:

```
@Entity(tableName = "words",
        foreignKeys = @ForeignKey(
                entity = Collection.class,
                parentColumns = "id",
                childColumns = "collId",
                onDelete = SET_DEFAULT),
        indices = @Index("collId"))
public class Word implements Serializable {

    @PrimaryKey
    @NonNull
    public final String id;

    public String wordTitle;

    public String collId;

    public String pageNum;

    public int isFavorite;

    public String wordNotes;

    @Ignore
    Word(String wordTitle, String collId, String pageNum, int isFavorite, String wordNotes) {
        this(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), wordTitle, collId, pageNum, isFavorite, wordNotes);
    }

    Word(@NonNull String id, String wordTitle, String collId, String pageNum, int isFavorite,
         String wordNotes) {
        this.id = id;
        this.wordTitle = wordTitle;
        this.collId = collId;
        this.pageNum = pageNum;
        this.isFavorite = isFavorite;
        this.wordNotes = wordNotes;
    }
}
```

At the time of inserting a new Collection, I give wordCount as 0 because every new collection would have 0 words associated with it. However, when inserting a new Word, I have to choose one collection from the defined collections and use its 'id' as 'collId' (Foreign Key).

Now I need to retrieve a list of Collection objects with 'wordCount' field containing the actual number of words associated with each Collection object. As already mentioned, 'wordCount' field is assigned a value of 0 at the time of insertion of a Collection object.

I just hope I made my question clear. Kindly suggest a query that serves my purpose. And I don't want to have the result in the form of a new POJO class like, for example, CollectionsAndWords.

Any help would be a great help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, i solved it in the following way:

In my Collection entity, I annotated the wordCount as follows:

```
@ColumnInfo(name = "word_count")
    public int wordCount;
```

and made changes to the constructors by removing this field:

```
Collection(String collTitle, int isFavorite) {
        this(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), collTitle, isFavorite);
    }

@Ignore
Collection(@NonNull String id, String collTitle, int isFavorite) {
        this.id = id;
        this.collTitle = collTitle;
        this.isFavorite = isFavorite;
   }
```

Finally, I added the following query method in my DAO:

```
@Query("SELECT collections.id, collections.collTitle, collections.isFavorite, " +
            "COUNT(words.collId) as word_count " +
            "FROM collections " +
            "LEFT JOIN words " +
            "ON collections.id = words.collId " +
            "GROUP BY collections.id " +
            "ORDER BY collections.collTitle")
List<Collection> findAllCollsWithCount();
```

The LEFT JOIN used in the right manner did all the trick for me.

Note that in above query, I'm not retrieving the wordCount field, I'm just letting a new field to be calculated and mapping it to wordCount. If I retrieve wordCount along with other columns from collections table, I get 02 columns that go by the name of word_count; one with 0 value and other with calculated value (COUNT()). I also tried to annotate wordCount with @Ignore but then Room couldn't find any column to map word_count to.

However, for now, the above solution is perfectly serving my purpose, so it is the answer. It might help someone with the same question.

Thanks!